# RSA: why does phi(phi(n)) work?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

Apparently an alternative method (to just using the extended Euclidean algorithm) of obtaining the exponent for deciphering is to do d = e**(phi(phi(n))-1) mod(phi(n)). Why does this work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The general requirement for the RSA operation to function properly is that `e*d = 1 mod X`, where `X` is typically `(p-1)*(q-1)`.

In this case, `X` is `phi(n)`, `e` is `e`, and `d` is `e^[phi(phi(n))-1]` = `e^[phi(X)-1]`.

Notice that `e*d mod X` is `e*e^[phi(X)-1] mod X` = `e^phi(X) mod X`.

[Euler's Theorem](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) states that `a^phi(X) = 1 mod X`, for any `a` which is relatively prime to `X`, thus the requirement holds.

Comment: All true except that X is not p*q. X is (p-1)*(q-1) where n=pq and p and q are both prime.